# How to keep css elements from moving during transition

Tags: html, css, transition

When I use the Transition on a css element the things below it move. Here is an example on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgdxd7su/ (Look at the JSFiddle one. The code snippet seems not to work)

```js
h1{
font-size
}
h1:hover{
         display: inline;
         font-size: 3em;
         -webkit-transition: font-size .2s linear;
         -moz-transition:    font-size .2s linear;
         -ms-transition:     font-size .2s linear;
         -o-transition:      font-size .2s linear;
         transition:         font-size .2s linear;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <hr>
      </body>
```

Would there be a way to fix this and keep the hr from moving?

Comment: why would you need the `<hr>` to be kept from moving? ain't it will make the `<hr>` and word `Hello` collapse with each other? and what did you need to fix? is it the bad transition when the animation start?

Comment: Sometimes you just need absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, the easy cross-browser answer is to change your HTML markup to this:

```
 <div id="h1box">
         <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
```

and then you can use your CSS like this:

```
#h1box {
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px left:5px;
}
h1:hover {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 3em;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -o-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    transition: font-size .2s linear;
}
```

Basically we're getting rid of the difference between browser renderings of `hr` element, using more simple and easily to adapt elements like `div`, then removing the flow of elements by applying a `position:absolute` to the `h1` element so the animation won't affect anything below it. Easy and cross-browser solution that will look teh same in every browser.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LctodyL0/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you need to fix is just the bad `animation` on hover, 
perhaps this is what you want: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/pgdxd7su/1/)

your `animation` looks bad because you declare `display: inline;` inside the `:hover` and not in the main `element` itself, which will make the default `display: block;` from the `<h1>` changed to `display: inline;` only when it's hovered. It's jumping up and down because an `inline element` can't have a `margin` which `<h1>` on default, so the what you need to avoid the bad `animation` is either change your style to one of this

```
h1 {
    -webkit-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -o-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    transition: font-size .2s linear;
}
h1:hover {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

this will keep the default `block` element of the `<h1>`

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -o-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    transition: font-size .2s linear;
}
h1:hover {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

this will change the default `block` element of the `<h1>` to `inline`

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    -o-transition: font-size .2s linear;
    transition: font-size .2s linear;
}
h1:hover {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

this will change the default `block` element of the `<h1>` to `inline` on `hover`, but removing the default `margin` which makes it jumpy (this will result the same with the second one)